# Copy only chosen subfolder from folder

Tags: powershell

I have a folder with many subfolders:

```
C:\Folder
-subf1
-subf2
-subf3
.
.
.
-subf100
```

From this folder I want to copy only the folders `subf2` and `subf100` with their content to `D:\test\`:

```
D:\test
-subf2
-subf100
```

I found `Copy-Item $from $to -Recurse -Force` and it works, but it changes the folder creation date to the current date.

I need to retain the original creation date of the source folder.

Comment: You may want to use [`robocopy`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145.aspx) for a task like that.

Comment: Here's a question that addresses retaining the timestamp and uses powershell: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21593625/how-to-use-powershell-to-copy-file-and-retain-original-timestamp