# Powershell: Copy file attributes (Creation.Time of *.AVCHD = Creation.Time of encoded *.mp4)

Tags: powershell, loops, timestamp

Good day,

I use a Panasonic camcorder for recording videos and compress the *.AVCHD files to *.mp4 files using HANDBRAKE. For archiving purposes, I need to copy the original file time stamps (creation date and time) to the encoded *.mp4 files. *.AVCHD files are located in folder test1 and *.mp4 files in folder test2. The files names are equal except the file ending.

I tried to modify this ([how to use powershell to copy file and retain original timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21593625/how-to-use-powershell-to-copy-file-and-retain-original-timestamp)
) solution to my needs but failed:

```
$AVCHD = 'test1'
$MP4 = 'test2'

$files = gci $AVCHD | % {$_.Name}

ForEach ($AVCHD_file in $files) {
  $MP4_file.Name = $AVCHD_file.BaseName + ".mp4"  
  $MP4_file.CreationTime = $AVCHD_file.CreationTime
  $MP4_file.LastAccessTime = $AVCHD_file.LastAccessTime
  $MP4_file.LastWriteTime = $AVCHD_file.LastWriteTime
}
```

Powershell complains that the file properties can not be found. What would I have to do next?

Thank you for your help,
Christian

Comment: Something is wrong in your loop  $MP4_file is not a file item, and it represents always th same thing. Do you want to copie and rename the file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `$MP4_file` is not an object, so there are no attributes or properties to be set.

The simple way to get a FileInfo object is to use gci and build suitable path based on source file's basename. Like so,

```
ForEach ($AVCHD_file in $files) {
    $MP4_file = gci $("$MP4\{0}.mp4" -f $AVCHD_file.basename)
    if (test-path $MP4_file ) {
        # Attribute set goes here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the line `$files = gci $AVCHD | % {$_.Name}` to `$files = gci $AVCHD` and try.

By declaring `$files` as `$files = gci $AVCHD | % {$_.Name}`, `$files` basically stores just the name of the files in the folder and nothing else. It doesn't contain any other property and hence, you are not able to use it.

Try changing `$files` to **`$files = gci $AVCHD`**. Now `$files` will contain all your required file properties and you will be able to use it as per requirement.

Comment: Consider improving the answer by explaining what the change is about and how it's going to fix the problem.

Comment: Yes @vonPryz. I have added the explanation. Was anyways going to do so.

Comment: I'd like to thank both of you a lot for your help! The resulting solution works like a charm and I understood what I did wrong.