# powershell download file preserving metadata

Tags: powershell, download, metadata, powershell-2.0

I am having difficulty figuring this one out. I am trying to download a file using powershell (via batch, so it must be on one line), but preserve the original creation date/time and modified date/time. The code I am currently using writes the date/time that the file was downloaded as the created & modified date.

```
(new-object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('https://file-examples.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/file_example_MP3_700KB.mp3','%USERPROFILE%\Downloads\file_example_MP3_700KB.mp3')
```

I've been able to accomplish this with a download manager, but I would like to be able to get this done via powershell so I can schedule the download on system start-up. I've searched for code to suit my needs, but can't find any that fit the criteria.

Ive found these, but i'm not sure how to incorporate them:

`.TimeLastModified` `.LastModified` `.LastWriteTime` `.CreationTime`

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked into robocopy?

Comment: Have you read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21593625/how-to-use-powershell-to-copy-file-and-retain-original-timestamp) stackoverflow answer?

Comment: @Walter, doesn't work. Server fault had a [similar](https://serverfault.com/questions/464058/robocopy-a-file-from-the-web) question.

Comment: @somebadhat Just now, yes. I couldn't find it because I was searching for different keywords. The question is phrased to make it sound like the process is happening on _local_ servers. Is the process the same for downloading from a remote server? I am not experienced enough with powershell to create a working example from scratch.

Comment: Your download manager can run in a scheduled task.

Comment: @somebadhat it’s not as simple as that, if it was, I wouldn’t be here. The download manager can be run as a scheduled task, but the download does not begin when the program is opened. Plus in the batch file I’m currently working on, it not only downloads the files based on the day of the week (using power shell) but it also moves the files to their appropriate locations and names the folder with the current date. If the script is ran more than once, it sees that the files have already been transferred over and closes out.

Comment: You might look into getting a windows copy of Curl. With the `-R` option, it will try to use the timestamp of the remote file on the downloaded file.

Comment: Comment to me when you have added to your question the following: Post working code I can use to download a file and what creation date / modified date the file should have.

Comment: @StarGeek that does indeed work, however the idea was to accomplish this all in powershell, without downloading additional software. Thank you, I will keep it in mind. I will revert to curl if I cannot find a solution in powershell.

Comment: @somebadhat the code to download is in the original post ```(new-object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('https://file-examples.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/file_example_MP3_700KB.mp3','%HOMEPATH%\Downloads\file_example_MP3_700KB.mp3')``` the created & modified time should read as Monday, ‎November ‎13, ‎2017

Comment: You probably will have to parse the http response header and set the time stamp from that.  A quick google seems to pull up some examples of getting the response.

Comment: `homepath` is wrong.  Probably should be `userprofile`

Comment: @somebadhat yeah I have updated it in my script since. They're both identical except ```homepath``` doesn't include the drive letter C

Comment: like apples and oranges are identical because they're both fruits?

Comment: does this help? https://pleasework.robbievance.net/howto-get-timestamp-of-file-from-ftp-site-using-powershell/

Answer (score 0):

Just use BITS, it copies remote file time by default and will even draw a nice progress bar when running interactively.

```
Start-BitsTransfer -Source 'https://google.com/favicon.ico' -Destination 'c:\Temp\2.ico'
```

My previous answer for history:

```
$request = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create('https://google.com/favicon.ico')
$response = $request.GetResponse()
$stream = $response.GetResponseStream()
$file = New-Object System.IO.FileInfo 'c:\Temp\1.ico'
$fileStream = $file.OpenWrite()
$stream.CopyTo($fileStream)
$stream.Close()
$fileStream.Close()
$file.CreationTime = $file.LastWriteTime = $response.LastModified
```

If the server does not report file time, it will be set to current time.

If you need an one-liner, combine the lines with `;`.

In PowerShell 3+ you can use a simpler alternative:

```
$fileName = 'c:\Temp\1.ico'
$response = Invoke-WebRequest 'https://google.com/favicon.ico' -OutFile $fileName -PassThru
$file = Get-ChildItem $fileName
$file.CreationTime = $file.LastWriteTime = $response.BaseResponse.LastModified
```

Comment: does BitsTransfer work with powershell 2.0? its telling me ```The term 'bitstransfer' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.```